# How to make the program restart if I press a certain button

Tags: c

I've recently written this "guess the number" program. My problem is that I want the program to restart when I press "y" after the "Play again" question comes. Any ideas? :)

```
srand( time(NULL) );
int secretNumber = rand()%100 + 1;
int guess = 0;
int counter = 0;


 printf("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100\n");
 printf("What is your guess?\n");

while(1)

{

 counter++; 

 scanf("%d", &guess);

 if (guess == secretNumber) 
 {
     printf("It took you %d tries\n", counter); 
     printf("Play again (y/n)?\n");
     break;

 }

 if (guess < secretNumber) 
  {   
     printf("Too low!\n"); 
  }


 if (guess > secretNumber) 

 { 
     printf("Too high!\n");
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't look like C#.

Comment: Are you sure you want "program to restart" or just "repeat the main game loop" - really different questions with completely different code...

Comment: `if (getc() == 'y') continue;` is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Put the entire code snippet you have inside another `while(1)` statement:

```
srand(time(NULL));
while(1)
{
    int secretNumber = rand()%100 + 1;
    int guess = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    printf("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100\n");
    printf("What is your guess?\n");

    while(1)
    {
        //code for guessing number
    }

    printf("Play again? ");
    if (getchar() != 'y')
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `srand()` can be called only once in the program, and generating a random number on each iteration doesn't seems a good idea.

Comment: @AlterMann Apart from srand() belonging *outside* of the loop, this answer seems correct to me.

Comment: @JonasWielicki, there could be repeated random numbers.

Comment: [Joking](http://dilbert.com/dyn/str_strip/000000000/00000000/0000000/000000/00000/2000/300/2318/2318.strip.gif) aside. But the point of the game is to re-pick a random number on each instanciation of the game. So you have to pick a random number during each iteration. What different approach would you suggest?

Comment: Maybe, but in the OP's code the random number is generated only once ;)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
printf("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100\n");
printf("What is your guess?\n");
```

needs to be inside your loop, unless you only want to give them one guess.

The easiest way to do what you want is to create a new secret number when they guess right, and bail out of your loop if they answer "No" to "do you want to play again?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use another variable. like below.

```
char userinput = 'y';
while(input == 'y')
{
    //your logic here
    //And at the end use one scanf

    printf("Play again (y/n)?\n");
    scanf("%c", &userinput);
}
```

You need to add one new variable, In above case it's userinput.

Answer (score 0):

use a while loop, with a loop variable of  type bool  say dec initially True. Put your code and initialize all the variables inside the loop, so that they can have a local scope and gets destroyed each time the loop is complete. Ask user for the dec variable if it presses  "y" set it to True else set it to False. so that the loop may be skipped this time

code may be like :

```
char cha;
bool dec=True;
while(dec){
srand( time(NULL) );
int secretNumber = rand()%100 + 1;
int guess = 0;
int counter = 0;
printf("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100\n");
printf("What is your guess?\n");

while(1)
{
    //code for guessing number
}

printf("Play again? ");
scanf("%c",&cha);
if (char== 'y')
    bool=True;
else bool=False;
}
```